# simple C++ regex got run-time error in OSX but windows

Tags: c++, regex, macos

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string str = "hello_2019";
    regex pattern[2];
    memset(pattern, 0, sizeof(regex) * 2);
    pattern[0] = regex(".*_\\d+");
    pattern[1] = regex("[a-z]+_.*");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << regex_match(str, pattern[i]) << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

[image]

But same code in OSX can't run:

[image]

Even using g++ can compile it, it results the run-time error.

```
g++ main.cpp
./a.out
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyPjy.png)    11669 segmentation fault  ./a.out

Comment: `memset(pattern, 0, sizeof(regex) * 2);` -- Why are you doing this?  You don't initialize objects this way (C++ is not C).  Also, the declaration of the `regex` array already default initializes those two elements.  Remove that line and try again.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh yes, delete this line it can print the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

`memset(pattern, 0, sizeof(regex) * 2);`

corrupts each of the `regex` objects in the `pattern` array.

Do not use `memset` to initialize non-POD objects such as `regex`.  Using `memset` here leads to *undefined behavior*.

The simplest solution is to just remove that line.  The array itself automatically default initializes the `regex` entries, so there is no need to (faultily) attempt to "zero-initialize" a `regex` object.